# any code with multiprocessing in python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, process-pool

I have a simple multiprocessing code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

This code gives same error repeated over(as given below) . Not only this, any library/function which internally calls multiprocessing module(eg-*reverse_geocoder, ProcessPoolExecutor in concurrent.futures* ) shows same error while ThreadPoolExecutor runs just fine!!! I am trying to run this in Pycharm, also, same code runs fine on another Pc in Pycharm
Please help.
**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\p\\r\\i\\b\\<input>'
```

Comment: how is this being run, exactly?

Comment: I am running it in Pycharm if that's what you mean.

Comment: Also, this code runs fine on another machine in Pycharm ! This problem something specific to my pc

Comment: Does it run fine outside of PyCharm on the machine that gives you the error?

Comment: No, I tried to run it in Jupiter , it's not running.

Comment: Not Jupyter, just run it normally, from the terminal.